# Is it incorrect to say "your grade is calculated by $\text{(grade / out of)} \times 100\%$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

Is it incorrect to say "your grade is calculated by $\text{(grade / out of)} \times 100\%$

$100\%$ is $1$ as a number.

So if you got $9/10$ on a test, your grade would actually be $90\%$

But the way many introductory textbooks put it is that your grade is $(9/10)\times 100\%$, which is wrong since this is $0.90$.

Should they instead write "your grade is calculated by $[\text{(grade / out of)} \times 100]\%$

When you want stuff expressed as a percentage, wouldn't it be more correct to put the **percentage symbol outside**?

Comment: $\left(\frac 9{10}\right) \times 100\% = .9 \times 100\% = 90\%$; on the scale of $1$ being perfect $\frac 9{10} = \frac {0.9}{1} = \frac{90}{100} = 90\%$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the % symbol as an abbreviation for $1/100$ then, for example, $$0.9 \times 100\% = 0.9 \times 100 \times 1/100 = 90 \times 1 / 100,$$ which is $90\%$ just as you would expect. This is the sense in which $100\%$ is $1$ as a number.

Because multiplication is associative, this means that it does not matter if the % sign is inside or outside the parentheses.